# Ocaml/C interop using bigarray: 'undefined symbol: caml_ba_alloc'

Tags: c, ocaml

I'm trying to compile a 'Hello World'-level Ocaml/C interop program that uses bigarray. I'm getting an error about  `undefined symbol: caml_ba_alloc`  (details below). It seems like it should be provided by `bigarray.h`.

Here are my files:

wrap_mylib.c:

```c
#include <caml/bigarray.h>
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>

CAMLprim value caml_fn(value x) {
    float* result = malloc(sizeof(float));
    long dims[] = {1, 1};

    return caml_ba_alloc(CAML_BA_NATIVE_INT, 2, result, dims);
}
```

`mylib.ml`:

```ml
external ext_caml_fn : int -> (float, Bigarray.float32_elt, Bigarray.c_layout) Bigarray.Array2.t
  = "caml_fn" ;;
```

`Makefile`:

```
wrap_mylib.o: wrap_mylib.c
    gcc -c wrap_mylib.c

another_wrapper.so: wrap_mylib.o
    cc -shared -o another_wrapper.so wrap_mylib.o

mylib.mli: mylib.ml
    ocamlc -i $< > $@

mylib.cmi: mylib.mli
    ocamlc -c $<

mylib.cmo: mylib.ml mylib.cmi
    ocamlc -c $<

mylib_test: mylib.cmo another_wrapper.so
    ocamlc -linkall -o mylib_test mylib.cmo another_wrapper.so

clean:
    rm *.cma *.cmo *.cmi *.cmx *.cmxa *.mli *.o *.a *.so
```

Here is the output when I try to compile `mylib_test`:

```
$ make mylib_test
ocamlc -i mylib.ml > mylib.mli
ocamlc -c mylib.mli
ocamlc -c mylib.ml
gcc -c wrap_mylib.c
cc -shared -o another_wrapper.so wrap_mylib.o
ocamlc -linkall -o mylib_test mylib.cmo another_wrapper.so
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error on dynamically loaded library: ./another_wrapper.so: ./another_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: caml_ba_alloc
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'mylib_test' failed
make: *** [mylib_test] Error 2
```

**Environment**

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

```
$ ocaml --version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.05.0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files like `bigarray.h` define things that are useful at compile time. But your problem is a link-time problem. You need to find the library that contains the function you're looking for and include it in the link step.

If I use ocamlopt (native code implementation) and use ordinary object files (OCaml .cmx and C .o) rather than a shared library, I can get things to link up like this:

```
$ ocamlopt -c mylib.ml
$ gcc -I $(ocamlc -where) -c wrap_mylib.c
$ ocamlopt -o mylib_test wrap_mylib.o mylib.cmx
```

This produces an executable mylib_test that I can run:

```
$ ./mylib_test
$
```

Of course nothing happens when I run the executable because there is no top-level code in your file mylib.ml. So this is just testing whether things will link up OK.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Very helpful! Additionally, your note about needing to find the library that contains the necessary function led to me finding a way to solve this using `ocamlc`. I've added it in a separate answer for the sake of completeness, but your solution is more straightforward and is the one I plan to use in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Here's how I was able to get it to work. Compile `mylib_test` by linking `bigarray.cma`:

```
ocamlc -linkall -o mylib_test mylib.cmo another_wrapper.so bigarray.cma
```

Then run with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./mylib_test
```

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` is necessary for it to find the shared library `another_wrapper.so` in the same directory.

According to https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libbigarray.html `bigarray` is now part of the standard library and so linking `bigarray.cma` should only be necessary when using the legacy compatibility library. Possibly my version of the standard library is old.